# replace numbers in php array with prefixed values

Tags: php

I have an array like:-

```
array(1,3,5,7,10,12)
```

I want to replace the numbers in the array with other fixed values. 
Example:-

```
1 -> 12
2 -> 44
3 -> 32
4 -> 27
5 -> 11
etc.
```

What is the best way to change these values in PHP?

Comment: What logic you are implementing to replace?

Comment: If you mean for what purpose it will be used? The fixed values are wordpress post id's.  I am trying to setup a function for converting values from an imported xml file. The first array is what i have in my xml file.

Comment: How it would decide 1 -> 12, 3 -> 44?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the way to have a switchcase in a foreach, but i don't know if it is the best way.

```
foreach ($values as $value){
    switch ($value){
            case 0:
                //make relative change;
                break;
            case 1:
                //make relative change;
                break;
            case 2:
                //make relative change;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Thx, i have used your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try [array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php);

```
array_replace($arr1, $arr2);
```